# How to save file using Eclipse Monkey?

Tags: eclipse, scripting, ide

I've recently started working with Aptana and Eclipse Monkey. What I want to do now is to create a script that saves a file then uploads it to a FTP.

Problem is that Eclipse Monkey is VERY poorly documented and Google returned only unrelated results.

I've made it upload the file, but I need the script to save the file before uploading.

```
sync.uploadCurrentEditor();
```

Do you know any resource for Eclipse Monkey with methods,etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out, it has the solution for your problem:

http://forums.aptana.com/viewtopic.php?t=5216

Edit; to be more specific;
You need to add the following line into the meta-data piece at the top, so the script knows the reference 'editors':

```
* DOM: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dash/update/org.eclipse.eclipsemonkey.lang.javascript
```

After you've done that, you need to add the following line right before the sync. stuff;

```
editors.activeEditor.save();
```

That's it :)